# Semi Transparent Background in Scene

Tags: sprites, flash, cocos2d, andengine

In my game I want to create game over scene which is semi transparent so game scene become partially visible.

Game over scene contain several button that are not transparent but I need only background become semi transparent.

I have used scene management structure so people have to consider this also.
I have already tried following things
*) set background enable method to true
*) create large rectangle up to screen size and set alpha.

But unfortunately about things not work for me. So please provide me some useful information about my problem.

Comment: Can you clarify:  do you want it to be semi-transparent over the android operating system or semi-transparent over other assets of yours?  Also, what was wrong with drawing an image and setting alpha?  (I.e., what about it didn't work?)

Comment: Why is this tagged flash, cocos2d and andengine?

Comment: I consider any platform I work same trick used so I placed well know platform tag. I use sprite and set alpha of it but it only generate black background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use simple dialog using layout file.
in this you can set transparent background.

i find one temporary solution for your que.
if you don't use background on scene then below code help you.
in this you can set background as sprite.

```
Scene yourGameOverScene = new Scene();
yourGameOverScene.setBackgroundEnabled(false);
Sprite spriteBG = new Sprite(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT,
                    dBgRegion);
spriteBG.setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA,
                    GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
spriteBG.setAlpha(0.1f);
yourGameOverScene.attachChild(spriteBG);
YourActivity.this.getEngine().setScene(yourGameOverScene);
```

Comment: I don't want to use any android stuff because now I only want to concentrate on game engine power. can I use transparent image and set alpha? I already tested but after showing others view. I have to look it again.

Comment: @Siddharth i update my ans, check it helpful or not.

Comment: I check this but it can't work so think about another solution for it.

Comment: it work perfect in my game play.
plz show your code.
can i send demo ???

Comment: yes mail me at siddharth3322@gmail.com. Thanks for your active attention.

Comment: @Siddharth send mail, plz check it working or not.

Answer (score -1):

Is there any reason you cannot use a semi-transparent .png as your background image, then layer whatever else you need on top of that?

Comment: I also tried that one but it create whole background black.